# How do I lower the saddle on a Scirocco bicycle?

Tags: saddle, seatpost

I've acquired a second-hand ladies' Scirocco Elegance 21 speed bicycle.  I need to lower the saddle but can't quite see how it can be done.

Comment: Is it possible for you to post some pictures of the seat post and the clamp? This way not only the people familiar with ladies' Scirocco Elegance bikes can help you.

Comment: To echo @Mike's comment, a photo would be really useful. Most bikes are the same in this regard, so with a picture to confirm that your bike does the usual thing, pretty much anyone should be able to help.

Comment: Looking at images on the web, the seatpost arrangement is relatively standard, but the collar is fairly small and likely requires an allen wrench to operate.  And, of course, as Argenti suggests, the post is likely frozen in the tube and will require some witch doctor incantations to loosen up.

Comment: I had to take the bike for servicing anyway as there was more wrong with it that I thought,so they took care of it.

Answer (score 6):

The saddle is supported by the *seat post* which is inserted into the *seat tube* of the frame. At the top of the seat tube there is a clamp which holds the seat post. On some bicycles this is built into the seat tube, on others it is a separate collar. Undo the seat post clamp bolt, and the seat post should slide in the seat tube.

I'm guessing that the above is obvious and you have loosened the clamp, but the seat post is not moving. Seat posts are notorious for getting stuck as water can seep between the post and frame tube and cause corrosion. If the post is not too badly stuck twisting the seat can unstick it. Using a penetrating oil such as WD-40 can help also.

If the seat post is really stuck there are many videos on YouTube documenting unsticking techniques.

If/when you do get the post loose, be careful to not overtighten the clamp after adjusting the saddle height. It's possible to damage the threads of the bolt or the clamp.

Comment: Before adjusting the saddle height, and especially if the seatpost has been stuck, it is a good idea to pull out the post completely and clean it. Also clean the seat tube as far down inside as possible and apply grease on the seatpost before re-inserting.